# Oauth using Birdy Python on Flask: Not able to figure out what to do with the Access Token

Tags: python, oauth, flask

This is my code to fetch the tweets based on keyword.
Here I am trying to Authenticate using Birdy Oauth API. But the problem is that I don't seem to understand why does it say that my token is expired when I enter the Token of my Application.

**Please give specific feedback on what seems to be the issue here**

```
import datetime
from config import CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, SAVED_ACCESS_TOKEN 
#Saved access token is a list of containing my apps Access token and 
#Access token secret as its elements

from birdy.twitter import AppClient
from app import app
from app import db
from models import TweetInfo 

#Create an instance of appclient for the application
client = AppClient(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, SAVED_ACCESS_TOKEN)

#Add the keywords here which need to be searched over Twitter
QUERIES = ['#Vespa', '@Vespa']

#A method to fetch all the new entries for statuses 
#regarding the keywords queried that do not have an entry in the DataBase
def get_new_tweets():
"""Return number of tweets if any and save them in Database"""
statuses = [] 
for query in QUERIES:
    response = client.api.search.tweets.get(q = query, count = 100)
    statuses += response.data.statuses

latest_tweets = 0
for status in statuses:
    if not db.session.query(TweetInfo).filter(TweetInfo.domain_id ==      status.id_str).count():  #check whether a tweet is already present in the DataBase
        created_at = datetime.datetime.strptime(status.created_at, r"%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y")
        o = TweetInfo(tweet = status.text,
                    posted_by = '{} ({})'.format(status.user.screen_name,
                        status.user.followers_count),
                    recorded_at = datetime.datetime.now(),
                    occured_at = created_at,
                    domain_id = status.id_str)
        latest_tweets += 1
        db.session.add(o)
db.session.commit()
return latest_tweets
```

Comment: The error just means that the access_token obtained previously has expired. You will have to authenticate and authorize the user again to get rid of the error.

Answer (score 0):

The Access Token is only valid for some time. So you have to get a new one with each Connection. Birdy will save it automaticaly. Remember with this auth you can only read.

Replace this

```
#Create an instance of appclient for the application
client = AppClient(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, SAVED_ACCESS_TOKEN)
```

With this

```
client = AppClient(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
access_token = client.get_access_token()
```